# Test Video Object using Selenium Chrome Driver in Java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, video, selenium-webdriver

I am developing selenium tests to detect whether video exists or not using **ChromeDriver** on **Chrome Browser**.

When the following code hits `chromedriver.get("http://d3o006n2t0jcdj.cloudfront.net/8348d175-9468-4b6c-9781-6dba4fdf4bfd.mp4")`, it opens it in the browser, and play's the video too but it **never hits next line to capture `WebElement` associated with it**.

How do I make sure that moment the video is opened in Chrome browser, it hits next line to capture 'WebElement'? Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
try {
    chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    chromeDriver.get("http://d3o006n2t0jcdj.cloudfront.net/8348d175-9468-4b6c-9781-6dba4fdf4bfd.mp4");
    WebElement videoCloudObject = chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/video/source"));
    logger.info("Video Cloud Object " + videoCloudObject + " .. Moving object  " + nonDuplicateVideoList.get(i));
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Moving object does not exist  " + nonDuplicateVideoList.get(i));
    Assert.fail("Video cannot be played as Moving image object does not exist " + nonDuplicateVideoList.get(i));
} finally {
    chromeDriver.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the *"bare" catch clause*. I suspect selenium finds the element but the error happens when you try to concatenate a string and a `WebElement` instance here:

```
logger.info("Video Cloud Object " + videoCloudObject + " .. Moving object  " + nonDuplicateVideoList.get(i));
```

Instead, you probably intended to get the `src` attribute of the `source` element:

```
videoCloudObject.getAttribute("src")
```

Comment: I added debug point at WebElement, but saw code is not hitting it, thereby selenium won't find the element. It launches the browser, and code hangs.

Comment: @Daksh could you just remove the exception handling and let it fail - what error are you getting - please post the traceback. Thanks!

Comment: I see the following message using Selenium Tests against Chrome broser if I remove the exception handling

    [302.282][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.777

Comment: These tests fails only in chrome browser, and works fine in Firefox. I am using chromedriver=2.20.353145, and chrome=45.0.2454.101